# Display the latest modified record for each employee

Tags: sql

emp table as like this

```
id     Name              Date Modified
1     Ram              2017-01-05
2     Kishore          2017-02-04
3    John             2017-04-22
1   Ram K             2017-04-25
1   Ram Kumar         2017-05-01
2   Kishore Babu      2017-05-05
3   John B            2017-06-01
```

Comment: This is for which `DBMS` ? Did you try anything to get the result

Comment: rdbms.......still im trying i wont get result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a reasonable [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms) that supports window functions, `row_number` should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, name, date_modified
FROM   (SELECT id, name, date_modified,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_modified DESC) rn
        FROM   emp) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: @chandu care to elaborate?

Comment: @mureinik....i cerated a table with 5 names and i updated only 3 rows...now,i want to display only which rows are updated previously

Comment: SELECT id, name, date_modified
FROM   (SELECT id, name, date_modified,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_modified DESC) rn
        FROM   emp) t
WHERE  rn = 1                        it will display all the rows..but i want only updated rows